# navigationItem not showing on popoverController

Tags: ios4, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller

The navigationbar is failing to appear, works fine in a UITableView, but fails inside a popoverController

Initiate a popover popoverController in UIViewController

```
-(IBAction) btnShowMovies:(id) sender {

    if (self.popoverController == nil) {

        teamAController *movies = 
        [[teamAController alloc] 
         initWithNibName:@"teamAController" 
         bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; 

        UIPopoverController *popover = 
        [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:movies]; 

        popover.delegate = self;
        [movies release];

        self.popoverController = popover;
        [popover release];
    }

    CGRect popoverRect = [self.view convertRect:[btn frame] 
                                       fromView:[btn superview]];

    popoverRect.size.width = MIN(popoverRect.size.width, 100);
    [self.popoverController 
     presentPopoverFromRect:popoverRect 
     inView:self.view 
     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown 
     animated:YES];
}
```

teamAController.h

```
@interface teamAController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {        
    UITableView *tableView;
    NSArray *theArray;
}    
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *theArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

-(void) createArray;
```

teamAController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.title= @"FooBarExtreme";    
    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(250.0, 300.0);        
    [self createArray];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Everything works, I have lovely table with images etc, correct sized and placed popover  just no title bar..... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution/problem by following the tutorial at http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/using-popoverview-ipad-app-development.

Worth noting that I found this the most comprehensive one on creating uiPopoverController with uiNavigationBar elements from UIButtons.

The issue is that the popover itself belongs to the view that calls it. The content is derived from the xlib/view you load into it. But not the titlebar. You call that in the parent view view.

This code is in the main view and is called from the UIButton

```
// BookMarksViewController is the class that contains the code/xib for the popover's content
// Of overarching importance is creating it as a UITableViewController

if (self.popoverController == nil) {
    BookMarksViewController *bookMarksViewController = 
    [[BookMarksViewController alloc]      
     initWithNibName:@"BookMarksViewController" 
     bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; 

    // Here's the rub: because in effect this view is controlling the popover
    // we have to assign nav bar stuff here. Sigh.
    bookMarksViewController.navigationItem.title = @"Territories";
    UINavigationController *navController = 
    [[UINavigationController alloc] 
     initWithRootViewController:bookMarksViewController];

    bookMarksViewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320, 400);

    UIPopoverController *popover = 
    [[UIPopoverController alloc] 
     initWithContentViewController:navController]; 

    popover.delegate = self;
    [bookMarksViewController release];
    [navController release];

    self.popoverController = popover;
    [popover release];
}

CGRect sourceRect = [self.view convertRect:[btn frame]  fromView:[btn superview]];

[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:sourceRect 
inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
```